# Textviews not at the right place

Tags: android, android-layout

I am really newbee in android.
I just want to create a layout with some textviews, a picture.

I made it, and it looks good on my editor. (I am using eclipse/adt).

When i tried it first, the result was horrible (see picture). After that i tried it on another config, what is still horrible.

As i know, the dp is for indepency, but as i see it is not. But i guess, i made something wrong.

Please help me, and enlighten me, what do i do wrong, and why is the textviews and the picture moves?

On the picture from left to right:

- Editor
- Eclair, 3.3 QVGA 320x480 mdpi
- Jelly Beans 3.2 WQVGA 240x400 ldpi

[image: textviews]

And my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/quizLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/quiz_background"
tools:context=".Quiz" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="@string/go" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="@string/question" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPoints"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvQuestion"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvQuestion"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="@string/points" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCarHolder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPoints"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPoints"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"

    android:contentDescription="@string/dummy" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should make different screen layout for different screen sizes.As value of dp changes for different screens it is necessary that you separately design them.

Comment: is that mean, i should define all views 4 times on the 4 different layout if i want to be success on xhdpi, ldpi, mdpi and hdpi, and create 4 pictures for them?

Comment: if you are using fixed values for hight or width or any other space context in any of your layout file i recommend you to go separately for each screen size.
As for example 35 dp is different for screen with resolution 360*480 and for 480*640.so your screen looks weird if you are using constants in large extents.

Comment: thank you for this, but now i can not accept your answer, because you just commented, not answered. if you copy this into an answer, i will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using fixed values for height or width or any other space context in any of your layout file i recommend you to go separately for each screen size. As for example 35 dp is different for screen with resolution 360*480 and for 480*640.so your screen looks weird if you are using constants in large extents.